# why does pushing to a new array gives me incorrect list of data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, permutation

1. I am expecting permutation array to be as below
2. but the result i am  getting on executing the code in the snippet is not what i want.
3. can someone explain me, why isnt the output as i expected.

> permutation [[ "a","b","a"],["b","a","a"],["a","a","b"]]

```js
function permAlone(str) {
  const createPermutation = () => {
    let arr = Array.from(str);
    let permutation = [];
    Array.from(str).forEach(_ele => {
        const first = arr.shift();
        arr = arr.concat(first);
        permutation.push(arr)
    });
    console.log('permutation',permutation);    
  };

  createPermutation();

  return str;
}

permAlone("aab");
```

[image]

Comment: What happens instead? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase as my second line says, have you run the snippet on stackoverflow itself to see the output? i have already mentioned the output i am getting, i puzzled why its happening thats the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you push `arr` to permutation it keeps a reference, when you modify arr on the subsequent iterations you modify it affects the content of the permutation array, a simple way force a copy of an array is using the method slice.

```js
function permAlone(str) {
  const createPermutation = () => {
    let arr = Array.from(str);
    let permutation = [];
    Array.from(str).forEach(_ele => {
        const first = arr.shift();
        arr = arr.concat(first);
        permutation.push(arr.slice())
    });
    console.log('permutation',permutation);    
  };

  createPermutation();

  return str;
}

permAlone("aab");
```

## clarification

In response to your comment I am crating a simpler example.

```js
const arr1 = []
const arr = []
arr.push(1)
arr1.push(arr)
console.log(arr1) // here you se what you would expect
arr.push(2) // arr1 has a reference to this object
console.log(arr1) // here you see that arr1 changed
```

If you push a slice this will add a copy of arr, instead of a reference to it

```js
const arr1 = []
const arr = []
arr.push(1)
arr1.push(arr.slice()) // what is added is a copy of arr
console.log(arr1) // here you se what you would expect
arr.push(2) // arr1 does not have a reference to this object
console.log(arr1) // here you see that arr1 is not changed
```

Comment: ok, i added console log before the         permutation.push(arr.slice()), and i can see the list having correct values.

but the permutation array doesnt reflect the same.

i get what you mean but its doesnt help me understand why is the array of array having different values

Comment: btw, i havent used arr.slice() because i want to know why would it print correct values but not push them to new array.

Comment: when it reaches line permutation.push, it already has concatenated so why not push the correct array to permutation arr, that would be right way to think i believe.

Comment: @hafizali The first value for all permutations is removed because you call [`shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) on each permutation except the last. By pushing a copy of `arr`, `arr` and the last `permutation` element will no longer refer to the same object. So calling `shift()` on `arr` will no longer effect the last `permutation` element.

Comment: @3limin4t0r but we are concatenating before permutation.push so it should make it proper, no? attaching the link here with output https://i.imgur.com/ngQEPTr.png

Comment: @hafizali `shift()` mutates the result of the previous iteration, not the current one. Try logging the last element of `permutation` each iteration, after shifting but before pushing the new element. `console.log(permutation[permutation.length - 1])`

Comment: @hafizali Check the clarification in my answer. Try to explain yourself the results in those examples, then it will become clear what is happening in your original example.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code was you were pushing deep copy of your arr array. Instead of that you should do shallow copy with using slice() method. When you deep copy the array it passes its address which changes its value after its last iteration instead of that you should pass array's value using slice method so that your code will work fine.

```js
function permAlone(str) {
  const createPermutation = () => {
    let arr = Array.from(str);
    let permutation = [];
    Array.from(str).forEach(_ele => {
        const first = arr.shift();
        arr = arr.concat(first);
        permutation.push(arr.slice())
    });
    console.log('permutation',permutation);    
  };

  createPermutation();

  return str;
}

permAlone("aab");
```